# Custom keyboard shortcut for "back"

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a Windows user who recently switched to elementary os. I want to know if it would be possible to assign the "backspace" key to the "back" command   when I'm using a browser or anything else (except while typing) ?